# How to differentiate multiple, identical form submissions based on their parent object in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm building a rails view that has lots of nested objects.  Each system has a subsystem, so I'm displaying a list of subsystems underneath each system.  I also want a little form bellow each system to add new subsystems.

```
= semantic_form_for @subsystem, :validate => true, :class => "subsystem_form" do        |subsystem_form|
  = subsystem_form.input :name
  = subsystem_form.input :maintenance_interval , :label => "Maintenance Interval(days)"
  = subsystem_form.input :run_hours
  = subsystem_form.buttons do
    = run_form.submit
```

I don't want the user to have to specify which system they're assigning the subsystem to. That should be dependent on which system the form is under.  So my question is: how do I pass that information to the controller so that the subsystem ends up with the correct system_id?  I was thinking about trying to manually add it to the params hash, but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested object then why you are not using nested forms.

Check this out https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

It will made your life much easier

Comment: Because I don't want to create new root objects, just append children to them.  Wait, would this might be possible using edit.. ok you've got me onto something